# jQuery setInterval giving Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good morning,  I created a function that gets all the USA timezone times and returns them to me highlighting which timezone you are in.  The issue is I want it to run every minute.  When I use the setInterval function I keep getting a javascript error saying 'invalid argument'.  Here is my code in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Qg2eL/

```
// Timezone
var arrTime = new Array();
var arrZone = new Array("ET","CT","MT","PT");

var getTimeZones = setInterval(timeZone(),60000);

function timeZone(){
    var location = 0;
    var current_date = new Date();
    var offset = parseInt(-current_date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60);

    switch(offset){
        case -5:
            location = 0;
            break;
        case -6:
            location = 1;
            break;
        case -7:
            location = 2;
            break;
        case -8:
            location = 3;
            break;
    }

    arrTime.length = 0;
    for(var x=5; x<9; x++){
        var current_date = new Date();
        var utc_hour = current_date.getUTCHours() - x;
        var utc_minutes = current_date.getUTCMinutes().toString();

        var dd = "AM";
        if(utc_hour >= 12){
            utc_hour = utc_hour - 12;
            dd = "PM";
        }
        if(utc_hour == 0){ utc_hour = 12; }
        utc_minutes = utc_minutes<10?"0"+utc_minutes:utc_minutes;

        var formattedTime = utc_hour+":"+utc_minutes+" "+dd;

        arrTime.push(formattedTime);
    }

    var strHTML = "";
    strHTML += "<ul>";
    for(var x=0; x<arrTime.length; x++){
        strHTML += "<li>"+arrZone[x]+": "+arrTime[x]+"</li>";
    }
    strHTML += "</ul>";

    $('.timezoneHolder').html(strHTML);
    $('.timezoneHolder ul li:nth-child('+(location+1)+')').css({
        "color":"lime",
        "font-weight":"bold"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very common mistake is that you're not passing the function to be executed but actually calling it in this line:

`var getTimeZones = setInterval(timeZone(),60000);`

Rather:

`var getTimeZones = setInterval(timeZone,60000);`

PS. tested in Chrome and IE. and no invalid argument popped up.

***Edit***: The reason you're not seeing it pop up after making your change is because it will only be executed after 60 seconds, so you should just call the function after your `setInterval` and will be executed every 60 seconds afterwards.

```
var getTimeZones = setInterval(timeZone,60000);
timeZone();
```

Comment: When I remove the () from the function call the timezones do not display at all.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.  Thanks a bunch.  I'll check you as correct as soon as stackoverflow allows.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

The setInterval function runs its own "callback" you could say. The syntax is just a little off. Try this:

```
var getTimeZones = setInterval(function() {
    timeZone();
},60000);
```

This syntax basically says, every 60000 milliseconds (or 60 seconds) perform the function inside of the interval. In this case the setInterval function calls your function.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I add function(){} the timezones don't display at all?

Comment: @seroth Do you get an error? I setup this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peJEX/) that merely pops up an alert and it seems to work alright. The timeZone function executes every 60 seconds. Does the console give any errors?

Comment: The issue was I needed to call the function after I setup teh interval to fire it the first time and not wait one minute for it to fire.  f0x showed me.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @seroth Not a problem man. Glad you got it fixed. Good luck and happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var getTimeZones = setInterval(timeZone,60000);
```

remove the brackets! :)